# Can an athlete with double nationality beat two country records at the same time?

Tags: records, track-and-field, athletics

There is a tweet about the recent European Athletics Championship in Berlin, 2018:

> U20 World Record
>   Swedish National Record
>   American Record
>   #2 World Outdoor Mark All-Time
>   #4 World Indoor/Outdoor Mark All-Time
>
> <sub>[FloTrack, 13 Aug 2018](https://twitter.com/FloTrack/status/1028783187277692929)</sub>

It links to the news [Mondo Duplantis Vaults 6.05m To Win European Championship](https://www.flotrack.org/events/6186907-2018-european-athletics-championships/videos?playing=6238882&limit=60) and talks about the case of [Armand "Mondo" Duplantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armand_Duplantis), who is both Swedish and American. Apparently, his 6.05 in pole vault is a record in both the USA and Sweden.

There are a lot of comments asking whether this is true or not, so is there any official source that confirm or deny this? Would this be the case for any other athlete with multiple nationalities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if the rules of the respective national athletics federations allow it. National records are governed by national athletics federations and, while everywhere the big line is that you need to be a citizen of the country to break a national record, there is no uniform way to define the national record of a country. The devil is in the details, as usually.

Let's consider the case of Duplantis, assuming that ratification happens smoothly (sending proof of doping control to the national federation and such)

### Swedish record

Not much doubt. He is a Swedish citizen, competing for Sweden at the European championships. The Swedish federation has a list of improved national records on their website. [His performances in Berlin are listed](http://www.friidrott.se/rs/rekord/swerek/swerek18.aspx).

### American record

this is the more contentious one as he was competing for Sweden instead of the USA. The rules of USATF are very clear:

> **RULE 261 NATIONAL RECORDS**
>
> 1. There shall be six (6) categories of national records as follows:
>
> (a) An  American  Record,  which  shall  be  the  best  performance made  by  an  American  citizen  or  relay  team  composed  entirely of  U.S. citizens in  an athletics  event  held  within the United States or abroad.

Is Duplantis a US citizen? Yes. This means he can break American records. While his record is as of today not listed on the website of USATF (because they only update the list at the end of the year) his performances of 2017 are [listed as American Junior Record](http://www.usatf.org/statistics/records/view.asp?division=american&location=outdoor%20track%20%26%20field&age=junior&sport=TF), for which the rules are

> An  American  Junior  Record,  which  shall  be  the  best  performance  made  by  an American citizen or relay team composed entirely of U.S. citizens who are Juniors. (See Classifications in Rule 141.)

Very hard to argue that he would be eligible for American Junior records, but not for American records.

While the US rules are very broad, many other federations have further rules. Often you need to be member of a club affiliated to the federation or eligible to compete for the country or something to that end. USATF can in the future restrict their rules, making Duplantis ineligible for American records, if they would feel inclined to do so. But under today's rules it is an American record.

Comment: Great one! Thanks a lot for the thorough answer, for which I would TL;DR: It really depends on the countries.